# Find the number of permutations with the given property

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I want to solve the problem
[image]

If the problem were to find the number of elements conjugate to $\tau$, I had to look for the permutations with the same structure. But, here the question is different.
Since $\tau$ and $\pi$ are conjugate to each other, there will be at least one $\sigma$ with the property for sure.

I tried taking an arbitrary $\sigma$ and substituting in the given equation to get some properties of $\sigma$ but didn't get any conclusion from it.

Please guide me to solve similar problems.

Comment: Think of conjugation as temporarily relabeling the elements, then applying the original permutation, then un-relabeling.

Comment: I think, this comment helps to find the number of conjugate elements of a permutation. I can't relate this to the particular problem.

Comment: But they are related. In general, if $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are conjugate in a finite group $G$, and $\tau$ has $k$ conjugates in $G$, then the set of elements conjugating $\tau$ to $\sigma$ is a coset of $C_G(\tau)$, and it has size $|G|/k$.

Comment: It sounds good. Can I get a reference for this in order to study more on this?

Comment: The fact that the size of a conjugacy class of $g$ is the index of the centralizer of $g$ is  a standard result in finite group theory.

Comment: I wish to get, How the number of $\sigma$ is coming same as a coset of CG(τ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjugating by $\sigma$ can take $2$ to any of $6$ different permissible locations -- anywhere that's involved in one of the $3$-cycles of $\pi$.  That choice determines where $5$ and $8$ have to go.  Once those choices have been made, conjugating by $\sigma$ can take $1$ to any of $3$ permissible locations (any point in the unused $3$-cycle of $\pi$), and that choice will determine where $6$ and $7$ have to go.  Once those two choices are made, $3$ can go to either of $2$ possible locations (one of the fixed points of $\pi$), and that final choice will determine where $4$ has to go (the unused fixed point of $\pi$).

So there are $6 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=36$ possible permutations $\sigma$ that conjugate $\tau$ to $\pi$.